# Which button does PHP choose when they have the same name?

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to make a very simple blog with php. My code snippet just generates a tile,text and the author plus an Edit button.
Because I'm working with the data from an array, I read it with a `for`.
Now when I want to edit a post it should take me on the site `editpost.php` but how do I mark which button belongs to which blogpost?
Do I need to generate a new form for every new post?

```
  echo '<form id=\"myform\" name=\"myform\" method=\"GET\">';
for ($i = count($liste) ; $i >= 0 ; $i--){
    echo '<p>';
    echo '<h2>'.$blogs[$i][0].'</h2><br>';
    echo $blogs [$i][1].'<br>';
    echo 'Autor:'.$blogs [$i][2].'<br>';
    echo '</p>';
    if($_SESSION['email'] == $blogs[$i][2]){
    echo '<input type=\'submit\' name=\'updatepost\' value="Edit Post">';}
    if (isset($_GET['updatepost'])){
        header ( 'Location: editPost.php' );
    }
}
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: If you have multiple `<input type="submit">` elements in a single form, the one clicked on to send the form will be the only one PHP receives.

Comment: If you do not want to use javascript, create a unique form for each submit button.

Comment: BTW: Why are you running your `for` loop downwards with `$i--`?

Comment: @ThomasLandauer Because the blog should show the newest blogs on the top, so I just changed the direction of the for. There is probalbly a easier way to do it but this was the only one, which came to my mind.

Answer (score 4):

PHP doesn't "choose" anything. They're processed strictly in the order that they appear in the HTTP request, from first-to-last.

Browsers USUALLY send things in strict html definition order - the order that fields appear in the html are the order they'll be sent out in.

That also means that if you send multiple fields with the same name, you'll end up with the value of the LAST of those duplicate fields. Which is why PHP has the `[]` naming hack. Note the following (not totally valid) HTML:

```
<input name="foo" value="bar" />
<input name="foo" value="baz" />
<input name="abc[]" value="def" />
<input name="abc[]" value="ghi" />
<input name="pqr[stu]" value="vwx" />
```

If this gets submitted to a PHP script, you'll end up with the following:

```
$_POST = array(
   'foo' => 'baz'   // note: baz is the LAST value in the form with this name
   'abc' => array(
       0 => 'def',
       1 => 'ghi'
    ),
    'pqr' => array(
       'stu' => 'vwx'
    )
);
```

Comment: So I simply need to add it like that? <br> <input type=\'submit\' name=\'updatepost[]\' value="Edit Post">

Comment: plus update your code to handle an array in `$_POST['updatepost']` instead of a single value.

Answer (score 0):

I see two easy solutions for this:

- Change your `<input>` to a simple link and append a query string, like this: `echo '<a href=\'editPost.php?id='.$i.'\'>';` In this case you don't need the entire `<form>` tag.
- Include a hidden `<input>` containing the id, like this: `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="$i">`. As @VIDesignz says, in this case you have to move the `<form>` tag into the `for` loop to create a separate form for each post.

I would say the first way is easier, since what you are having here is no real *form* (with input fields) anyway.

Comment: The second option won't work if they are all in the same form, there is no way to distinguish which button was clicked without using js.

Comment: How can I use the id on the next page?

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass a value to each submit like this:

```
echo '<input type=\'submit\' name=\'updatepost['.$i.']\' value="Edit Post">';}
if (isset($_GET['updatepost'])){
    header ( 'Location: editPost.php?id='.key($_GET['updatepost']) );
}
```

Comment: The part with the id works well but how can I use the id in the next page, with $id?